# MDX Query Assistance for Filter with 2 Dimensions

Tags: mdx

Trying to apply a filter with 2 dimensions values.

```
SELECT [Measures].[OrdItemCount] ON 0,
{
FILTER
(
[Date].[Date].[Date],
[Date].[Date].[Date].MEMBERVALUE = Format(Now(), "yyyyMMdd"))
)
}.ITEM(0)
ON 1
FROM
[Adventure Works]
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your requirement is to get the `OrdItemCount` for today. If so, use the query below:

```
with member [Measures].now as
now(), format_string = "yyyymmdd"

SELECT [Measures].OrdItemCount ON 0,
{FILTER([Date].[Date].[Date], [Date].[Date].MEMBERVALUE = [Measures].now)}.ITEM(0) on 1
from [Adventure Works]
```